# Using a method from a derived class with an object of base class type

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

I have a method inside my derived class that I don't have in my base class, is there any way to use the derived class method on an object with the base class type? I know that  I can move the method to my base class but I don't think I am supposed to do that..

Here is the code:

I want to use CalculateInterest() on my accounts in my loop, but the accounts are all of type Account, not SavingsAccount.

Method in SavingsAccount class:

```
 public decimal CalculateInterest()
        {
            return AcctBalance * interestRate;
        }
```

Loop in Main:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

            Account sAcct1 = new SavingsAccount(200, 0.10M);
            Account sAcct2 = new SavingsAccount(300, 0.12M);
            Account cAcct1 = new CheckingAccount(500, 2.00M);
            Account cAcct2 = new CheckingAccount(400, 1.50M);

            accounts.Add(sAcct1);
            accounts.Add(sAcct2);
            accounts.Add(cAcct1);
            accounts.Add(cAcct2);
foreach (Account account in accounts)
            {
                account.Debit(decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                account.Credit(decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                if (account.GetType().ToString().Contains("SavingsAccount"))
                {
                    //calculate interest if object is a savings account
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, probably best to have a default implementation of `calculateInterest()` in the base class that does nothing.

Subclasses would override to provide account-type-specific interest calculations.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but then, wouldn't I have to add a default implementation for every single method for every single class I derive from the Account class? Is that how it's normally done or is that necessary?

Comment: @Maximus9000 Subclasses inherit the behavior of their parent, that's kind of the point: you only provide subclass implementations if the behavior is different.

Comment: Yes but, I guess what I'm asking is that only the a SavingsAccount should be able to CalculateInterest(), CheckingAccount should not be able to CalculateInterest(). Which got me thinking, what if i had 50 classes and each one had a specific method that I didn't want to allow for any other class, I would have to have a default implementation in the base class for each one?

Comment: But if there is a subclass for which it doesn't make sense to calculate interest, wouldn't you be breaking the Liskov substitution principle?

Comment: @Maximus9000 No, you'd need to redesign then.

Comment: @Jubbat Depends what LSP is. You're assuming a pretty short hierarchy; in real life you'd have an InterestBearingAccount type.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, there is no subclass of SavingsAccount, all the accounts are of the Account type (the base class). I have two more classes called SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount, both inherit from Account, however I only want the SavingsAccount to have the CalculateInterest method (that is what my teacher specifically requested at the end of my assignment) which is why I'm so confused I suppose lol

Comment: @Maximus9000 Well if it's a requirement that only `SavingsAccount` have the method, then use `instanceOf`, or something like Mike's solution of a `process` method, which in `SavingsAccount` would do interest calculations. Usually best to mention reqs up-front to save time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a language specific thing, more than object orientation. Specifically Java, although the code is not exactly Java.

In any case, if you want to have a structure of one type and call a method of a subclass, then simply perform a cast on the object, previously using the instanceof operator to check the class.

That is probably not the most elegant solution, it depends on your problem, so it's hard to say which pattern or way to organise your code you can use with the information at hand.

One clue your code provides is that you are processing all accounts, and for some of them calculating interest. It seems like your method could be doing two or more things at the same time and might need to split into two or more methods to improve readability (possibly). Whatever you are trying to accomplish thinking harder about the proper design might end up solving the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  you could try to cast each Account to a SavingsAccount

```
if (account as SavingsAccount != null) { //calculate interest }
```

But I would say there is nothing wrong with implementing calculateInterest in the base class and then override it if necessary (e.g. SavingsAccount would override it, CheckingAccount would not) as mentioned by Dave Newton.

Maybe the best method though is to encapsulate the account processing into a new method (called "process" maybe?) and implement it appropriately in each case. E.g. in Account

```
public void process()
{
                this.Debit(decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                this.Credit(decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

and then override this in SavingsAccount

```
public override void process()
{
                base.process();
                //now calculate interest
}
```

This would avoid having a method implemented in the base classes that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Except for classes where there's no `process`ing required. It just moves the issue around, providing a non-specific means of implementing functionality.

Comment: As I posted below if you have calculateInterest in the base class all classes in the hierarchy should be able to calculate interest. It is bad design to leave a method empty if that class is not supposed to implement the method and it goes against the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: True, if there are any classes with no processing. Maybe "process" is a fundamental feature of all Accounts. The poster is writing code that does some common operations on Accounts, plus a specialised operation on a sub-class.

Comment: My comment is aimed at Dave Newton, not Jubbat :o)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much going to make an answer inspired by parts of the other answers :)

I'd leave `Debit()` and `Credit()` as methods on `Account` rather than hiding them inside a black-box `Process()` method, as real-life `Accounts` can be debited and credited, so this seems a more appropriate model to me. I'd suggest one of two ways to include a `CalculateInterest()` method.

**First option**: As alluded to by @Dave Newton, define an `IInterestBearingAccount` interface which has a `CalculateInterest()` method on it, then implement this in `SavingsAccount`. Your loop in main can then say:

```
var interestBearingAccount = account as IInterestBearingAccount;

if (interestBearingAccount != null)
{
    interestBearingAccount.CalculateInterest();
}
```

This gives you what you want without putting the knowledge that `SavingsAccounts` calculate interest while other `Accounts` do not into the `Main` method where it does not belong.

**Second option** - on a tangent from @Dave Newton's answer - have an empty `virtual` method on `Account` named `CalculateSupplementals` (or something like that), and have `Main` call that. `SavingsAccount` can implement it to calculate interest, and `CheckingAccount` can do nothing. The method on the base class is generically-named so that implementing classes can use it as a hook to do extra calculations if appropriate for the type of account they represent; it doesn't put information about a derived class' details into the base class, and provides somewhere for other classes to do work specific to them.

My personal preference is probably the first option as it doesn't add anything to the hierarchy just to satisfy a want of a derived class.